# Fastest Way for Converting an Object to Double?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-3.5

What is the fastest way to convert an object to a double? I'm at a piece of code right now, which reads:

```
var d = double.TryParse(o.ToString(), out d);  // o is the Object...
```

First thoughts were to rewrite this as

```
var d = Convert.ToDouble(o);
```

but would that actually be faster?

**EDIT:**  In addition to running the profile (by the way, I strongly recommend **JetBrains dotTrace** to any developer), I ran Reflector, and that helped me to come up with the following (more or less the relevant portion of the code):

```
if (o is IConvertible)
{
    d = ((IConvertible)o).ToDouble(null);
}
else
{
    d = 0d;
}
```

The original code `double.TryParse()` executed in 140ms.  The new code executes in 34ms. I'm almost certain that this is the optimization path I should take, but before I do that, does anyone see anything problematic with my "optimized" code?  Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: Is o *actually* a double or a string?

Comment: is `o` expected to be a double or is it an object which can be converted to a double (e.g. a string or something else)

Comment: Might be simple but can't you use a cast?

Comment: @Chris, o usually going to be either double or null.  Very, very rarely, it may be a real string, but I'll have to exclude those cases  out of the code block.

Comment: @Michael, o will usually be an IConvertible, dunno if that will help.

Comment: @Jonathan, yeah, I was thinking of that... but I figured I should ask everyone first hand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must be doing a whole whopping lot of these in order to make any sense to spend any time on this.  However, I am not here to judge:

So, your code is this:

```
if (o is IConvertible)
{
    d = ((IConvertible)o).ToDouble(null);
}
else
{
    d = 0d;
}
```

I wonder if you would be better off with this

```
IConvertible convert = o as IConvertible;

if (convert != null)
{
  d = convert.ToDouble(null);
}
else
{
  d = 0d;
}
```

Saves you the double cast.

Comment: 40,000 calls to this one function... that's the reason!

Comment: Great, well check out if it would be better without doing the double cast.  Can't see how it wouldn't be.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.  I'm going to take it, it makes sense.

Comment: Which is true for me every once in a great while!

Comment: I found that if o == DBNull.Value the ToDouble will throw an exception.  Might want to use: if ((convert != null) && (convert != DBNull.Value))

Comment: d = o is IConvertible value ? value.ToDouble(null) : 0d;
For the oneliners

Comment: Sidenote to @Jim 's oneliner: compiles with c# 9.0+ only (at least regarding to VS 2019)

Answer (score 14):

I tried the following methods.

- double.TryParse
- double.Parse
- Convert.ToDouble

I used the following code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string text = "3.14";
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        double d;
        d = Convert.ToDouble(text);
        //double.TryParse(text, out d);
        //d = double.Parse(text);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time=" + timer.Elapsed.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

On my machine I saw these results. I averaged 3 different runs.

- double.TryParse = 4.45 seconds
- double.Parse = 4.45 seconds
- Convert.ToDouble = 4.75 seconds

Of course, I used a string that was convertable. If the string is not convertable then I highly suspect `double.TryParse` will be the fastest by a long shot.

Comment: did you mean seconds, or milliseconds?

Comment: @code4life - He probably meant seconds, due to the fact he did 10,000,000 conversions within that time period.

Comment: thanks for the footwork!  By the way, I did some more profiling and double.TryParse is not performant for objects purely because it only supports strings... hence objects need to be converted to string first then passed to the method, so 2 calls.  Profiling shows it's a poor performer.  But definitely outperforms when dealing only with strings (unfortunately not my case)

Answer (score 3):

Create a small test app using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and see which comes out as faster.  Though I would argue this wouldn't make a worthwhile difference.  I'd go for `Convert.ToDouble` purely for readability.

Comment: good suggestion, I'll go for it.  One point: I'm into the performance optimization phase of the project, so readability is going to slowly get deprecated in favor of sheer performance (that's where we're at... sigh!)

Comment: @code4life -  its often good to optimize for performance, but don't do premature microoptimizations without fully understanding what needs to be optimized, it can just end up introducing harder to read, more error prone code while wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different things you could be trying to do, depending on what sort of thing o is. It could be

a) a boxed double, and you just want to unbox it:

```
object o = 53.2;
double d = (double)o;
```

b) some other type, value or reference, that has some conversion to double available (implements IConvertible.ToDouble()) that you want to use

```
object o = 53.2M; // a System.Decimal
double d = Convert.ToDouble(o);
```

or

c) something which has a default string representation that can be parsed as a double

```
object o = "53.2";
double d;
bool convertedOK = double.TryParse(o.ToString(), out d);
```

Option c is, in a sense, the longest way round; you're taking your object, asking for its string representation, then trying to parse that string to get a double. This is clunky if you don't need to do it, and in your example of 40,000 calls it's going to create and discard 40,000 strings...

If you know that your object will always contain something that implements a conversion to double, you can skip all that and go for option b. And if you know that your object will just be a boxed double, go for the simplest option (a) to just unbox it.

Maybe something along these lines would work for you, if you genuinely don't know what o will be?

```
double d = (o is double) ? (double)o
    : (o is IConvertible) ? (o as IConvertible).ToDouble(null)
    : double.Parse(o.ToString());
```

(note: this won't work if o contains something that implements IConvertible but can't be converted to double, or if its string representation can't be parsed as a double)

I haven't said anything about relative speeds, but I'd be amazed if unboxing wasn't substantially quicker than converting to string and then parsing (unless the optimizer is crazy clever).

A quick test in LINQPad using the .NET Stopwatch suggests a big difference.

```
IEnumerable<object> myData = new List<object>() { "53.2", 53.2M, 53.2D };
const int iterations = 10000000;
var sw = new Stopwatch();
var results = new List<string>();

foreach (var o in myData)
{
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    for (var i=0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        double d = (o is double) ? (double)o
            : (o is IConvertible) ? (o as IConvertible).ToDouble(null)
            : double.Parse(o.ToString());
    }

    sw.Stop();

    results.Add($"{o.GetType()}: {iterations} iterations took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}

results.Dump();
```

on my PC gives the following results

```
System.String: 10000000 iterations took 1329ms 
System.Decimal: 10000000 iterations took 402ms 
System.Double: 10000000 iterations took 38ms
```

Comment: The information originates from a non-.NET source (via COM), so unboxing is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

First, if you really want to know which is faster, you should write a quick test (using the data you expect to be processing) and time each option.  Without knowing what `o` is (or is likely to be) it's very hard to judge.  I suspect you're not going to see much difference.

Second, unless you're calling this bit of code in an *extremely* time-critical portion of your code, and calling it thousands of time to boot, I doubt it really matters.  Write good, clean code, *then* optimize.

Comment: And when you optimize, _always_ optimize based on a profiler.

Comment: it was clean... but the code gets called over 40,000 times in one particular iteration.  I'm profiling the code, and it was taking 140ms to execute, which in the project I'm working on is represents a big performance lag (believe it or not!).  I'd like to make it go faster than that.